# GZWeb: Security Options?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

Quick question about gzweb, the web client for Gazebo. I've set it up and it's working perfectly, no problems connecting. Is there any way to put some sort of security on it though? With the default install, I can connect to the web client from any computer on the open internet, which is a bit unnerving. Can access to the WebUI be credential protected in some way, or perhaps limited to access from specific IPs?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8350/gzweb:-security-options?/) by [Jordan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1165/jordan/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 25 on 2015-03-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi Jordan,

Unfortunately, gzweb does not support any security for the moment. We will probably add it as a feature in the future, but there is no time frame. If you want to add your own, you will have to secure 2 separate servers:

- The node http server that serves the web app (in http/client)
- The websocket server that publishes and subscribes to the Gazebo server (gzbridge)

Hugo Boyer,
OSRF

---

Originally posted by [hugomatic](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/59/hugomatic/) with karma: 116 on 2015-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jordan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1165/jordan/) on 2015-03-31**:
Unfortunate, but a quick and clear answer. Thank you.